# Iframe can't display HTML while a browser can

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am having hard time to make my Iframe display my html string which happens to be :

```
var='<BODY style="MARGIN: 0px" bgColor=#ffffff marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<SCRIPT language=JavaScript>
var Caller_User_Type = 'ESS';
var Locale_Date_Order = '2';
var User_Browser_Type = '';
var Page_ID = '266';
</SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT language=javascript>
var wlocationxx = '';
wlocationxx = String(window.location);
if (wlocationxx.substring(0,7) == 'http://'){
    window.location = 'https://' + wlocationxx.substring(7)
}
</SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT language=JavaScript type=text/javascript src="../../../System/CONFIG/Common_Functions.js"></SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT language=JavaScript type=text/javascript src="../../../scripts/modeling_script.js"></SCRIPT>

<TABLE id=PageStart_1 border=0 cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width="100%" height="100%">
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD height="100%" vAlign=top>
<TABLE id=PageStart_2 border=0 cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width="100%" height="100%" valign="top">
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD height="1%" width="100%">
<SCRIPT language=javascript src="../../../System/EXB/EXB_Includes/logout.js"></SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT language=javaScript src="../../../System/EXB/EXB_Includes/EXB_cookie_factory.js"></SCRIPT>

<TABLE border=0 cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width="100%">
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD>
<TABLE border=0 cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width="100%" bgColor=#000063>
<TBODY>
<TR bgColor=#000066>
<TD bgColor=#000066 height=60 vAlign=center colSpan=2><IMG src="../../../System/EXB/EXB_Images/exb_login/mckinseyLogo.gif" width=212 height=23> </TD>
<TD bgColor=#000066 vAlign=center align=right><FONT color=white size=2 face="Arial Rounded MT Bold">myaccount.mckinsey.com</FONT>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD><IMG src="../../../System/EXB/EXB_Images/mck_racing_stripe.gif" width=309 height=3></TD>
<TD width="100%"><IMG src="../../../System/EXB/EXB_Images/mck_racing_stripe.gif" width="100%" height=3></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE><!-- begin exb_global.asp --><!-- end exb_global.asp -->
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="../../../System/EXB/EXB_Includes/Menu/HM_Config_Common.js"></SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT language=JavaScript type=text/javascript src="../../../System/EXB/EXB_Includes/Menu/HM_mnu_functions.js"></SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT language=JavaScript type=text/javascript src="../../../System/EXB/EXB_Includes/Menu/HM_dummy_functions.js"></SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT type=text/javascript>var sHMConfigContent = "SetUpdateDefaults('300375');HM_TopLevelMenuId=\"hmExbDCPart\";nMenuItems=0;sHM_f_SetItems=\"\";sHM_f_SetItems=\"\";sHM_f_SetItems+=GetMenuItemString(\"hmExbDCPart\",\"Home\",\"\",\"65\",\"24\",\"\",\"\",\"EXB_RSQ_Home.asp\",true,\"\");sHM_f_SetItems+=GetMenuItemString(\"hmExbDCPart\",\"Select Plan\",\"\",\"65\",\"24\",\"\",\"\",\"EXB_RSQ_Part_Plan_Select.asp\",false,\"\");sHM_f_SetItems+=GetMenuItemString(\"hmExbDCPart\",\"Account Menu\",\"\",\"65\",\"24\",\"\",\"\",\"EXB_RSQ_Home.asp\",false,\"hmExbDCPart_AccountMenu\");sHM_f_SetItems+=GetMenuItemString(\"hmExbDCPart\",\"Withdrawals\",\"\",\"65\",\"24\",\"\",\"\",\"EXB_RSQ_Distribution_Security.asp\",false,\"\");sHM_f_SetItems+=GetMenuItemString(\"hmExbDCPart\",\"Annual Decisions\",\"\",\"65\",\"24\",\"\",\"\",\"EXB_RSQ_Rebalance_Elections_View.asp\",false,\"hmExbDCPart_AnnualDecisions\");sHM_f_SetItems+=GetMenuItemString(\"hmExbDCPart\",\"Administration\",\"\",\"65\",\"24\",\"\",\"\",\"EXB_RSQ_Personal_Profile.asp\",false,\"hmExbDCPart_Administration\");sHM_f_SetItems+=GetMenuItemString(\"hmExbDCPart\",\"Contact Us\",\"\",\"65\",\"24\",\"\",\"\",\"EXB_RSQ_Contact_us.asp\",false,\"\");sHM_f_SetItems+=GetMenuItemString(\"hmExbDCPart\",\"Log Off\",\"\",\"65\",\"24\",\"\",\"\",\"javascript:User_Log_Off()\",false,\"\");if(sHM_f_SetItems!=\"\"){var sTopMenuY=\"HM_f_GetElementXY('hm_m_dc_part_placer','y')+\";sTopMenuY+=\"(HM_f_GetElementXY('horizontal_ruler','y')-\";sTopMenuY+=\"(HM_f_GetElementXY('hm_m_dc_part_placer','y')+HM_f_GetMenuDimension(HM_TopLevelMenuId, false)))\";HM_f_SetMenus({TopMenuX:\"HM_window_right_edge-HM_f_GetMenuDimension(HM_TopLevelMenuId,true)-10\",TopMenuY:sTopMenuY,TopKeepInWindowX:0,TopKeepInWindowY:0,IsPermanent:1,IsHorizontal:1,PositionChild:\"below\",MilliSecondsVisible:0,CreateOnLoad:true,MenuID:HM_TopLevelMenuId});eval(\"HM_f_SetItems(\"+sHM_f_SetItems+\");\");HM_f_SetMenuTemplate({SeparatorColor:\"white\",BorderColor:\"#000000\",    BGColorOver:\"#FF9900\",BGColor:\"#DB5500\",BorderWidth:1,FontColor:((cssStyleObj!=null)?cssStyleObj.color:\"#ffffff\"),FontColorOver:((cssStyleObj!=null)?cssStyleObj.color:\"#ffffff\"),FontColorSelected:((cssStyleObj!=null)?cssStyleObj.color:\"#ffffff\"),MoreImagesVisible:true,ImageSrc:HM_imgsrc+\"/HM_More_white_right.gif\",HM_OnVisibilityToggle:HM_fc_HideControls});sHM_f_SetItems=\"\";sHM_f_SetItems+=GetMenuItemString(\"hmExbDCPart_AccountMenu\",\"Balances\",\"\",\"65\",\"24\",\"\",\"\",\"EXB_RSQ_Balances.asp?f=byfund-true&f=byaccount-true&f=webchart-true\",true,\"\");sHM_f_SetItems+=GetMenuItemString(\"hmExbDCPart_AccountMenu\",\"Account Summary\",\"\",\"65\",\"24\",\"\",\"\",\"EXB_RSQ_Account_Summary.asp\",false,\"\");sHM_f_SetItems+=GetMenuItemString(\"hmExbDCPart_AccountMenu\",\"Beneficiaries\",\"\",\"65\",\"24\",\"\",\"\",\"EXB_RSQ_Beneficiary.asp\",false,\"\");sHM_f_SetItems+=GetMenuItemString(\"hmExbDCPart_AccountMenu\",\"Contributions With Growth\",\"\",\"65\",\"24\",\"\",\"\",\"EXB_RSQ_Cost_Basis.asp\",false,\"\");sHM_f_SetItems+=GetMenuItemString(\"hmExbDCPart_AccountMenu\",\"Instant Statement\",\"\",\"65\",\"24\",\"\",\"\",\"EXB_RSQ_Instant_Statement.asp\",false,\"\");sHM_f_SetItems+=GetMenuItemString(\"hmExbDCPart_AccountMenu\",\"Loans\",\"\",\"65\",\"24\",\"\",\"\",\"EXB_RSQ_Loan_Inquiry.asp\",false,\"\");sHM_f_SetItems+=GetMenuItemString(\"hmExbDCPart_AccountMenu\",\"Pending Requests\",\"\",\"65\",\"24\",\"\",\"\",\"EXB_RSQ_Pending_Request.asp\",false,\"\");sHM_f_SetItems+=GetMenuItemString(\"hmExbDCPart_AccountMenu\",\"Plan Information and Forms\",\"\",\"65\",\"24\",\"\",\"\",\"EXB_RSQ_Request_Documents.asp\",false,\"\");sHM_f_SetItems+=GetMenuItemString(\"hmExbDCPart_AccountMenu\",\"Roth Conversion/Rollover\",\"\",\"65\",\"24\",\"\",\"\",\"EXB_RSQ_IPRC_Security.asp\",false,\"\");sHM_f_SetItems+=GetMenuItemString(\"hmExbDCPart_AccountMenu\",\"Statement\",\"\",\"65\",\"24\",\"\",\"\",\"EXB_RSQ_Individual_Statements.asp\",false,\"\");if(sHM_f_SetItems!=\"\"){HM_f_SetMenus({MenuID:\"hmExbDCPart_AccountMenu\"});eval(\"HM_f_SetItems(\"+ sHM_f_SetItems+\");\");}sHM_f_SetItems=\"\";sHM_f_SetItems+=GetMenuItemString(\"hmExbDCPart_AnnualDecisions\",\"Asset Allocation\",\"\",\"65\",\"24\",\"\",\"\",\"EXB_RSQ_Rebalance_Elections_View.asp\",true,\"\");sHM_f_SetItems+=GetMenuItemString(\"hmExbDCPart_AnnualDecisions\",\"Exchange Rates\",\"\",\"65\",\"24\",\"\",\"\",\"EXB_RSQ_Exchange_Rate_Inquiry.asp\",false,\"\");sHM_f_SetItems+=GetMenuItemString(\"hmExbDCPart_AnnualDecisions\",\"Historical Performance\",\"\",\"65\",\"24\",\"\",\"\",\"EXB_RSQ_Historical_Investment_Performance.asp\",false,\"\");if(sHM_f_SetItems!=\"\"){HM_f_SetMenus({MenuID:\"hmExbDCPart_AnnualDecisions\"});eval(\"HM_f_SetItems(\"+ sHM_f_SetItems+\");\");}sHM_f_SetItems=\"\";sHM_f_SetItems+=GetMenuItemString(\"hmExbDCPart_Administration\",\"Personal Profile\",\"\",\"65\",\"24\",\"\",\"\",\"EXB_RSQ_Personal_Profile.asp\",true,\"\");sHM_f_SetItems+=GetMenuItemString(\"hmExbDCPart_Administration\",\"Password Changes\",\"\",\"65\",\"24\",\"\",\"\",\"EXB_RSQ_Pin_Change.asp\",false,\"\");if(sHM_f_SetItems!=\"\"){HM_f_SetMenus({MenuID:\"hmExbDCPart_Administration\"});eval(\"HM_f_SetItems(\"+ sHM_f_SetItems+\");\");}}";if(window.event + "" == "undefined") event = null;function HM_f_PopUp(){return false};function HM_f_PopDown(){return false};HM_ConfigFiles="HM_Config_Menu.js";</SCRIPT>
<!--EXB_DC_Infobar.asp-->
<TABLE id=Table1 border=0 cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width="100%"><!--begin infobar table-->
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD bgColor=#db5500 width="100%"><IMG id=hm_m_dc_part_placer alt="" src="../../../System/EXB/EXB_Images/t.gif" width=1 height=21> </TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD colSpan=14><IMG id=horizontal_ruler src="../../../System/EXB/EXB_Images/horizontal_rule.gif" width="100%" height=3></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE><!-- end of infobar -->
<SCRIPT language=JavaScript1.2 type=text/javascript src="../../../System/EXB/EXB_Includes/Menu/HM_Loader.js"></SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="../../../../System/EXB/EXB_Includes/Menu/HM_ScriptDOM.js">
</SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="../../../../System/EXB/EXB_Includes/Menu/HM_Config_Menu.js">
</SCRIPT>
</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD height="100%" vAlign=top width="100%">
<TABLE id=PageStart_5 border=0 cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 height="100%" valign="top">
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD height="100%" vAlign=top>
<TABLE id=PageStart_6 border=0 cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width="100%" height="100%" valign="top">
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD class=Body_Title9pt height="100%" vAlign=top><!-- begin exb_global.asp --><!-- end exb_global.asp -->
<SCRIPT language=javaScript type=text/javascript>
    <!-- Begin
        var contentEcomp = "";
        var contentInfoLinx = "";

        function winOpen(url)
        {
            if (url.substr(11, 5) == "ecomp")
            {
                contentEcomp = window.open(url,"contentEcomp","resizable=yes,toolbar=yes,location=yes,width=800," +
                                            "height=500,directories=no,status=no,scroll=yes,scrollbars=yes,menubar=yes,left=200,top=100");
                contentEcomp.focus();                                       
            }
            if (url.substr(7, 5) == "infol")
                alert('To log in, use the following (case sensitive) credentials - Username: Consulting2005, Password: clientinfolinx')  ;
            {
                contentInfoLinx = window.open(url,"contentInfoLinx","resizable=yes,toolbar=yes,location=yes,width=800," +
                                "height=500,directories=no,status=no,scroll=yes,scrollbars=yes,menubar=yes,left=200,top=100"); 
                contentInfoLinx.focus();
            }
        }
    //-->   
    </SCRIPT>

<TABLE border=0 cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=3 width="100%" height="100%" valign="top">
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD>&nbsp; </TD>
<TD rowSpan=20><IMG src="../../../system/exb/exb_images/vert_black_bar.gif" width=1 height="100%"> </TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD class=Body_Title8pt><B>Welcome</B><BR></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD class=Body_Value9pt>Rahul Raina<BR><BR></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD class=Body_Title8pt><B>Plan Sponsor:</B><BR></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD class=Body_Value8pt>McKinsey &amp; Company<BR></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD class=Body_Title8pt><B>Plan Name:</B><BR></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD class=Body_Value8pt>Retirement Program (Profit-Sharing Retirement Plan (PSRP) and Money Purchase Pension Plan (MPPP), where applicable)<BR><BR></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD height="100%"></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE><IMG border=0 src="images/clear_px.gif" width=160 height=1> </TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></TD>
<TD class=Body_Title9pt height="100%">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD>
<TD height="100%" vAlign=top width="100%"><!-- begin exb_global.asp --><!-- end exb_global.asp -->
<FORM id=frmHome method=post name=frmHome><INPUT id=postAction type=hidden name=postAction> <BR>
<TABLE id=Table1 border=0 cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width="100%" valign="top">
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD class=Body_Value16pt>Home</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD class=Body_Value9pt>&nbsp;</TD></TR><!-- 0011 S, 0013, 0014 --><!--<tr>
            <td class="Body_Value9pt">Submit your annual Asset Allocation form between September 15 and October 6, 2008. </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="Body_Value9pt">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr> --><!-- 0011 E --><!-- 0009 S --><!-- <tr>
            <td class="Body_Value10pt">
                <a href="EXB_RSQ_Rebalance_Elections_View.asp">
                <font color="#db5500"><b>Click here to complete your Asset Allocation form</b></font></a>
            </td>
        </tr> --><!-- 0009 E--></TBODY></TABLE><BR><INPUT id=sMassAnouncementXML value='<?xml version="1.0"?><anouncement_text><rows>0</rows></anouncement_text>' type=hidden name=sMassAnouncementXML> <INPUT id=isMessageViewed value=True type=hidden name=isMessageViewed> <INPUT id=sSubGroup value=D218354ECFF824224F45F173EC46FFED type=hidden name=sSubGroup> 
<TABLE id=Table3 border=1 rules=none cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width="80%">
<TBODY>
<TR class=Table_Header>
<TD width=5></TD>
<TD><B>Special Message from McKinsey &amp; Company</B></TD>
<TD width=10></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD height=8 colSpan=3></TD></TR>
<TR class=Body_Value8pt>
<TD width=5></TD>
<TD><B>Do we have your current e-mail address?</B><BR>To confirm or update your e-mail address, go to Administration Menu&gt;Personal Profile. 
<P></P><B>The 2013 Annual Decisions Period is over.</B><BR>Your next opportunity to change your allocation will be in the fall of 2014. 
<P></P></TD><!-- 0026: removed <b> tags -->
<TD width=10></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD height=8 colSpan=3></TD></TR>
<TR class=Table_Header>
<TD width=5></TD>
<TD><B>Participant Information</B></TD>
<TD width=10></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD height=8 colSpan=3></TD></TR>
<TR class=Body_Value8pt>
<TD></TD>
<TD>Rahul Raina</TD>
<TD></TD></TR>
<TR class=Body_Value8pt>
<TD></TD>
<TD>Bangalore</TD>
<TD></TD></TR>
<TR class=Body_Value8pt>
<TD></TD>
<TD>Karanataka,<SPACE> <SPACE><SPACE>560001</TD>
<TD></TD></TR>
<TR class=Body_Value8pt height=20 vAlign=bottom>
<TD></TD>
<TD>Email Address: <B>mail@raina7.com</B> </TD>
<TD></TD></TR>
<TR class=Body_Value8pt height=20 vAlign=bottom>
<TD></TD>
<TD>Plan Status: Term &amp; Awaiting Payment</TD>
<TD></TD></TR>
<TR height=5></TR>
<TR>
<TD height=8 colSpan=3></TD></TR>
<TR class=Table_Header>
<TD width=5></TD>
<TD><B>Balance Information</B></TD>
<TD width=10></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD height=8 colSpan=3></TD></TR>
<TR class=Body_Value8pt>
<TD></TD>
<TD height=20 vAlign=top>Account balances are current as of October 31, 2013.</TD>
<TD></TD>
<TR>
<TR class=Body_Value8pt>
<TD></TD>
<TD>Value $98,390.82</TD>
<TD></TD></TR>
<TR height=5></TR>
<TR>
<TD height=8 colSpan=3></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE><BR><BR>
<P><A href="EXB_RSQ_Instant_Statement.asp"><FONT size=2 face="verdana, helvetica, arial"><B>Click here for an Instant Web Statement</B></FONT></A></P><BR></FORM>
<SCRIPT language=Javascript>

//0023
    function fn_getReport(siteURL)
    {
        document.frmHome.postAction.value = "report";
        document.frmHome.submit();
    }

    function winOpen(siteURL)
    {
        window.open(siteURL, "","resizable=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,width=640," +
                                                            "height=480,directories=no,status=no,scroll=yes,scrollbars=yes,menubar=no,left=100,top=20");
    }

//0005  -S
    function OpenAnouncement(PlanID,GroupID,PartID)
    {

        var url = "../../../System/Exb/Exb_Includes/RSQ_Mass_Anouncement.asp?read=" + 
                  document.getElementById("isMessageViewed").value + 
                  "&groupid=" + GroupID +
                  "&subgroupid=" + document.getElementById("sSubGroup").value ;

        if(document.getElementById("imgNew") != null)
        {
            document.getElementById("imgNew").style.display = "none";
        }   

        var popupwindow = "";
        popupwindow = window.open(url,"Mass_Announcement","resizable=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,width=500," +
                    "height=500,directories=no,status=no,scrollbars=yes,menubar=no,left=200,top=100");
        popupwindow.focus();
    }
//0005  -E
</SCRIPT>
</TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD align=middle>
<TABLE border=0 cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width="100%">
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD class=StatusBar2 height=20 width="50%"><A href="javascript:winOpenCopyright_RSQ();">Copyright 2003 Aon Consulting</A></TD>
<TD class=StatusBar2 height=20 width="50%" align=right><A href="javascript:winOpenPrivacy_RSQ();">Security and Privacy Statement</A></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD class=StatusBar1 height=20 colSpan=2 align=middle><A href="EXB_RSQ_Contact_Us.asp">Contact Us</A> | <A href="javascript:print();">Print Screen</A> | <A href="javascript:User_Log_Off();">Log Off</A></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE><!--
Start: 12/8/2013 10:46:06 AM
End  : 12/8/2013 10:46:07 AM
Host : 192.168.11.106
-->
<DIV style="Z-INDEX: 5000; BORDER-BOTTOM: transparent 0px solid; POSITION: absolute; BORDER-LEFT: transparent 0px solid; WIDTH: 686px; HEIGHT: 22px; VISIBILITY: visible; OVERFLOW: hidden; BORDER-TOP: transparent 0px solid; TOP: 66px; CURSOR: default; BORDER-RIGHT: transparent 0px solid; LEFT: 292px" id=hmExbDCPart title="" sp="null">
<DIV style="POSITION: absolute; PADDING-BOTTOM: 4px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #db5500; FONT-STYLE: normal; PADDING-LEFT: 4px; WIDTH: 47px; PADDING-RIGHT: 4px; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana, Verdana, Tahoma; HEIGHT: 22px; VISIBILITY: inherit; FONT-SIZE: 9pt; OVERFLOW: hidden; TOP: 0px; CURSOR: hand; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; BORDER-RIGHT: #666666 1px solid; PADDING-TOP: 4px; LEFT: 0px" id=hmExbDCPart_I1 title="" hh="46">Home</DIV>
<DIV style="POSITION: absolute; PADDING-BOTTOM: 4px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #db5500; FONT-STYLE: normal; PADDING-LEFT: 4px; WIDTH: 83px; PADDING-RIGHT: 4px; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana, Verdana, Tahoma; HEIGHT: 22px; VISIBILITY: inherit; FONT-SIZE: 9pt; OVERFLOW: hidden; TOP: 0px; CURSOR: hand; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; BORDER-RIGHT: #666666 1px solid; PADDING-TOP: 4px; LEFT: 47px" id=hmExbDCPart_I2 title="" hh="82">Select Plan</DIV>
<DIV style="POSITION: absolute; PADDING-BOTTOM: 4px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #db5500; FONT-STYLE: normal; PADDING-LEFT: 4px; WIDTH: 100px; PADDING-RIGHT: 4px; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana, Verdana, Tahoma; HEIGHT: 22px; VISIBILITY: inherit; FONT-SIZE: 9pt; OVERFLOW: hidden; TOP: 0px; CURSOR: hand; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; BORDER-RIGHT: #666666 1px solid; PADDING-TOP: 4px; LEFT: 130px" id=hmExbDCPart_I3 title="" hh="99">Account Menu</DIV>
<DIV style="POSITION: absolute; PADDING-BOTTOM: 4px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #db5500; FONT-STYLE: normal; PADDING-LEFT: 4px; WIDTH: 93px; PADDING-RIGHT: 4px; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana, Verdana, Tahoma; HEIGHT: 22px; VISIBILITY: inherit; FONT-SIZE: 9pt; OVERFLOW: hidden; TOP: 0px; CURSOR: hand; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; BORDER-RIGHT: #666666 1px solid; PADDING-TOP: 4px; LEFT: 230px" id=hmExbDCPart_I4 title="" hh="92">Withdrawals</DIV>
<DIV style="POSITION: absolute; PADDING-BOTTOM: 4px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #db5500; FONT-STYLE: normal; PADDING-LEFT: 4px; WIDTH: 121px; PADDING-RIGHT: 4px; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana, Verdana, Tahoma; HEIGHT: 22px; VISIBILITY: inherit; FONT-SIZE: 9pt; OVERFLOW: hidden; TOP: 0px; CURSOR: hand; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; BORDER-RIGHT: #666666 1px solid; PADDING-TOP: 4px; LEFT: 323px" id=hmExbDCPart_I5 title="" hh="120">Annual Decisions</DIV>
<DIV style="POSITION: absolute; PADDING-BOTTOM: 4px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #db5500; FONT-STYLE: normal; PADDING-LEFT: 4px; WIDTH: 105px; PADDING-RIGHT: 4px; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana, Verdana, Tahoma; HEIGHT: 22px; VISIBILITY: inherit; FONT-SIZE: 9pt; OVERFLOW: hidden; TOP: 0px; CURSOR: hand; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; BORDER-RIGHT: #666666 1px solid; PADDING-TOP: 4px; LEFT: 444px" id=hmExbDCPart_I6 title="" hh="104">Administration</DIV>
<DIV style="POSITION: absolute; PADDING-BOTTOM: 4px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #db5500; FONT-STYLE: normal; PADDING-LEFT: 4px; WIDTH: 80px; PADDING-RIGHT: 4px; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana, Verdana, Tahoma; HEIGHT: 22px; VISIBILITY: inherit; FONT-SIZE: 9pt; OVERFLOW: hidden; TOP: 0px; CURSOR: hand; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; BORDER-RIGHT: #666666 1px solid; PADDING-TOP: 4px; LEFT: 549px" id=hmExbDCPart_I7 title="" hh="79">Contact Us</DIV>
<DIV style="POSITION: absolute; PADDING-BOTTOM: 4px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #db5500; FONT-STYLE: normal; PADDING-LEFT: 4px; WIDTH: 57px; PADDING-RIGHT: 4px; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana, Verdana, Tahoma; HEIGHT: 22px; VISIBILITY: inherit; FONT-SIZE: 9pt; OVERFLOW: hidden; TOP: 0px; CURSOR: hand; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; PADDING-TOP: 4px; LEFT: 629px" id=hmExbDCPart_I8 title="" hh="57">Log Off</DIV></DIV></BODY>'
```

Please ignore the complex html page code. I just want to say that when I copy this in a notepad and save it as a .html page It renders the page properly which should have been.

[image: This is how it should look like]

But when I am trying to display this in an iframe using this it doesn't display anything:

```
var textBody = $(printstr);
var iframeBody = $('#test').contents().find('body');
iframeBody.append(textBody.html());
```

Here `printstr` is the string that contains the html string. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your code doesn't really start with `var='<BODY ...` does it? If so, then check your console for the syntax error that's causing.

Comment: says : SyntaxError: Failed to execute query: '<BODY style and then a long string.
code: 12
name:"Syntax error

Comment: OK, well that'd be a big part of the problem.  Another problem you're going to have is that it's invalid in JavaScript to split strings across line boundaries. *Another* problem will be that you're trying to embed plain single-quote characters in a string that's delimited by single-quotes.

Comment: so what should i do @Pointy

Comment: Well, I'll type in an answer. However I'll also say that you should take some time to learn more about basic JavaScript coding and debugging. There are lots of good online tutorials and courses at Codeacademy and Khan Academy etc.

Answer (score 3):

A good way to store large blobs of page content that you want to use from JavaScript (where by "good" I mean, at least, "much better than as a gigantic JavaScript string constant") is to use a `<script>` element with a non-executable "type" attribute:

```
<script id=frameContent type=text/content>
   <BODY class=whatever>
      <!-- ... -->
   </BODY>
</script>
```

Then you can fetch the contents of the script by accessing the `.innerHTML` property of  the DOM element. (That's why the example gives the element an "id" value — it makes it easy to find.)

Now, in your case, this approach will run into a problem because you're trying to include all those `<script>` elements inside the frame content. That could be worked around by using some alternative marker instead of the `</script>` closing tags:

```
<script id=frameContent type=text/content>
   <BODY class=whatever>
      <!-- ... -->
      <script src=some/script.js><@script>
   </BODY>
</script>
```

Then when you fetch the content you'd replace "@script" with "/script":

```
var frameContent = document.getElementById("frameContent")
  .innerHTML
  .replace(/@script/ig, "/" + "script");
```

---

A completely different approach would be to drop the idea of including your frame content like that, and simply host that page on your server and let the browser fetch it separately. It'd be much less messy, at the cost of an added HTTP transaction.

Comment: I still don't get it how would I apply this to my scenario. Here have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/37WRC/3/) to know what i am trying to i am extracting the html string from a page and trying to display it in a iframe . This fiddle has a simple html string but actually I need to make it work on the string i showed in the question.

Comment: @rahul888 right - so my suggestion is that you store the content for the frame in a non-JavaScript `<script>` tag, as described above. Your code then fetches the content, fixes up the protected "@script" closing tags, and then stuffs it into the iframe.

Comment: so how do i add these `<script>` tag to this string.>?

Comment: You don't add them to the *string* - you put the content in `<script>` tags in your HTML source, and then you *fetch* the content from JavaScript.